# Series of wheel. Permutation

Tags: combinatorics

Series of 77 wheel are connected. Let $k_i$ is $i$-wheel. My question is if $k_1$ moves $k_2$, $k_2$ moves $k_3$, $\dots$, $k_{77}$ moves $k_{1}$ then these system of wheels will be working?

My solution:
Assume that $k_{77}$ is moved so $k_{76}$ is moved, $\dots$, $k_{2}$ is moved by $k_{1}$, which is moved by $k_{77}$. I think this is wrong. Can we explain what is wrong or give a hint?

Comment: Try to imagine a working system of 3 wheels connected in a loop...

Comment: @MikeEarnest How do you work so damn fast lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let's say $k_1$ rotates clockwise.

- Which way does $k_2$ rotate?
- How about $k_3$?
- How about $k_{77}$?
- What does the above imply?

Comment: Oh my god. It's easy. Thanks. I closed question.